# cURL upload to YouTube, not working (via curl.exe/DOS) - YT server returns "Empty reply from Server"

Tags: curl, youtube-api

I try uploading a small section of an flv to YouTube via cURL and no luck.

Here's a section of the trace:


== Info: About to connect() to gdata.youtube.com port 80 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 74.125.228.69...
== Info: connected
== Info: Connected to gdata.youtube.com (74.125.228.69) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 658 bytes (0x292)
0000: POST /action/GetUploadToken HTTP/1.1
0026: User-Agent: curl/7.28.1
003f: Accept: */*
004c: Host: uploads.gdata.youtube.com
006d: Authorization: Bearer=ACCESS-TOKEN
0190: GData-Version: 2
01a2: X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER-KEY
0217: Slug: test2.flv
0228: Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9"
0268: Content-Length: 8192
027e: Connection:Close
0290: 
=> Send data, 7832 bytes (0x1e98)
0000: 
0002: 
0004: 
0006: --a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9
001c: 
001e: 
0020: 
0022: Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
0055: 
0057: 
0059: 
005b: 
009b: m"" xmlns:media=""http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"" xmlns:yt=""htt
00db: p://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007"">
011b: ype=""plain"">Eucharist Promo
015b: pe=""plain"">EWTN Promo for TV show Eucharist
019b: >
01db: categories.cat"">EducationEucha
021b: rist, EWTN
024e: 
0250: --a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9
0266: 
0268: Content-Type: video/x-flv
0283: 
0285: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
02a8: 
02aa: 
02ac:    .ftypmp42    mp42mp41  Fpmoov   lmvhd    .8T..8T. .*. )^  .  

02ec: .            .               .              @                   

032c:            .  '.trak   \tkhd   ..8T..8T.   .     )JP            

036c:      .               .              @   .@   .     $edts   .elst

03ac:        . )JP  .. .    'tmdia    mdhd    .8T..8T.  u0 ..p..     D

03ec: hdlr        vide            Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler 



++++++++++++++++++MORE BINARY CODE IN HERE++++++++++++++



1dec:   ..  .v  .@  ..  ..  ..  .f  .*  .v  ..  .y  *T  ..  ..  ..  ..
1e2c:   .,  .{  .S  .G  ..  .d  ..  .r  .{  ..  ..  .2  ..  ..  ..  ..
1e6c:   ..  ..  
1e78: 
1e7a: 
1e7c: --a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9--
1e94: 
1e96: 
== Info: upload completely sent off: 7832 out of 7832 bytes
== Info: Empty reply from server
== Info: Connection #0 to host gdata.youtube.com left intact
== Info: Closing connection #0

Answer (score 1):

The [browser-based upload flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading) that you're trying to use isn't really appropriate for uploads from the command line.

The [direct upload flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading) is more appropriate.

Even better, try using one of the supported [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/youtube/code) and avoid doing this by hand in cURL (unless you really want to).